# allocating four object arrays with one 'new'

Tags: c++, arrays, class, dynamic

I have a class with four dynamic arrays like this:

```
CObjA * objAArray;
CObjB * objBArray;
CObjC * objCArray;
CObjD * objDArray;
```

and I initialize those like this:

```
objAArray = new CObjA[numObj];
objBArray = new CObjB[numObj];
objCArray = new CObjC[numObj];
objDArray = new CObjD[numObj];
```

The problem is that those four memory allocations take a long time - performance is very bad if I have to create 40'000 objects like this.

my question is: is there a way to allocate all four arrays with one `new` operation?

If I create a new struct:

```
struct _arrays
{
 CObjA objA;
 CObjB objB;
 CObjC objC;
 CObjD objD;
};
```

and use one array of that struct instead, I only have to use one `new`:

```
_arrays * arr = new _arrays[numObj];
```

But then the objects are not laid out in memory correctly. They're then in memory as `CObjA1-CObjB1-CObjC1-CObjD1-CObjA2-CObjB2...`. instead of first all `CObjA` objects, then all `CObjB` objects, ...

Is there a way to use one `new` but still get the correct memory layout of the objects?

Comment: I would investigate whether the bottleneck is just raw the memory allocation or the construction of the objects.

Comment: I already did that: it's really the memory allocation, not the object construction. The objects are basically just structs of floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RSahu mentioned in his comment on your question, I would be surprised if it wasn't the construction of the object that was causing the performance bottleneck, and was the raw memory allocation itself. That said, one way to do what you want is to allocate one array with a `char *` type and then assign memory locations to your arrays afterwards, as below:

```
char* allocations = new char[numObj * (sizeof(CObjA) + sizeof(CObjB) +
                                       sizeof(CObjC) + sizeof(CObjD))];
CObjA * objAArray = reinterpret_cast<CObjA *>(allocations);
CObjB * objBArray = reinterpret_cast<CObjB *>(allocations + numObj * sizeof(CObjA));
CObjC * objCArray = reinterpret_cast<CObjC *>(allocations + numObj * (sizeof(CObjA) 
                                                                    + sizeof(CObjB));
CObjD * objDArray = reinterpret_cast<CObjD *>(allocations + numObj * (sizeof(CObjA)
                                                                    + sizeof(CObjB)
                                                                    + sizeof(CObjC));
... //use arrays here
delete [] allocations; //deletes all allocations in one go
```

Comment: This won't work properly if CObjA has constructors. "Placement new" is needed here.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you need using a single allocation by malloc then use the "placement new" syntax to create objects at their required memory positions.